# Bios date changes after Windows 7 installation in Laptop

Tags: windows-7, windows, bios, date

BIOS have correct date and time, but after Windows 7 installation system show date and time 6 year earlier (2012). When you set time in Windows suddenly bios date is set to 2024. Hardware is Acer 5741g.

What could cause this problem and how to fix this?

Comment: Your Windows 7 installation is fully patched?  I would make sure your system can reach your time server

Comment: I mesure voltage over BIOS battery it shows 2,7V. On the Battery there is indication 3V. Should I replace battery?

Comment: Do you mean the CMOS battery? Proper terminology is really important to use.

Comment: Yes. Voltage at CMOS battery is 2.7V. Other bios options are preserved if changed. Only date/time is changing by itself all the time.

Comment: It’s a worth a try but honestly I suspect your unable then communicate with a time server

Comment: I need to clear it. Date/time changes after laptop restart. Date/time is correct after i connect to server. Also there is weird issue when I change something at BIOS and save, some Windows tray icons are not visible. they appear after second restart(without changing BIOS settings)

Comment: In this case I would recommend to change the CMOS battery!